# Word Counter Implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm

Is there a better way than the following brute foce implementation of a c# word counting class?

UPDATED CODE: Sorry!

```
/// <summary>
/// A word counting class.
/// </summary>
public class WordCounter
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dictTest = new Dictionary<string, int> ();

    /// <summary>
    /// Enters a word and returns the current number of times that word was found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="word">The word or string found.</param>
    /// <returns>Count of times Found() was called with provided word.</returns>
    public int Found ( string word )
    {
        int count = 1;
        return dictTest.TryGetValue ( word, out count ) ? ++dictTest[word] : dictTest[word] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or are you not using 'word' anywhere in your body?

Comment: @shakedown: `"tt"` should be `word`.

Comment: yes "tt" should be word. thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: Umm... what?  Nothing that this code does in any way fits into my definition of "word count".  Can you be more clear about your end-game here?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Kenny, I think that this method of using a dictionary to count things is a pretty standard way to do it which should work for most purposes. Depending on your purpose for this there might be better options, but this will most likely be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a Tree and then search will take constant time in the length of the string, you are searching for. A Tree is more space efficient in this case, than using a hash.

Comment: I found this article based on your suggestion, which seems to suggest using a SortedDictionary rather than Dictionary since it stores the items in a red/black Tree. http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable

Answer (score 1):

In response to matt, Dictionary is basically a HashTable with generics, so the lookup is constant time (well, not exactly but pretty much).

Answer (score 0):

well, If you had like LOTS of memories, you could store all the letters individually in a tree structure.

so like, you have an array of 26 objects, first letter is the index into that array, the array is an array of pointers to more arrays of 26 objects (but only if that letter has been encountered of course.  so on and so forth, the second letter is the index into the second level of arrays...

does Dictionary use a Binary search pattern? also, does it search by string? or does it hash the strings down, if not, hashing the strings down to ints *might* improve performance.  also theoretically, if you did it manually, there wouldn't be any overhead in keeping the list "sorted" because the initial binary search would give up at roughly the position where it should be inserted in the list if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Oh I have memories, but they have nothing to do with computers. ;)